# Why can the labelsep of \uput not work when represented in RPN?

Tags: pstricks, postscript

In order to be more noticeable, I present [my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62887/how-to-use-a-pstverb-constant-as-the-angle-arguments-of-uput#comment236909_62890) as a new question here.

### Background:

`\uput` with the following syntax

[image]

accept 5 arguments. I have tested the last four arguments that they can be represented in RPN. The first argument is the only one cannot be represented in RPN.

### Question:

Why can the first argument of `\uput` not be represented in RPN? Is it a bug? You can try `\uput{! 2 sqrt}[!0]{!0}(!0 0){Hello World}` to put `Hello World` `\sqrt{2}` unit length away to the right of the origin `(0,0)`, but it fails.

Comment: This isn't an issue about RPN.  You're trying to pass postscript code through the arguments.  I haven't played too much with `\uput`.  As I get a chance today, I'll look at this.

Comment: @A.Ellett: So the first argument cannot accept RPN expression?

Comment: Postscript is written in RPN.  After an initial look at `pstricks.tex`, it looks like `\uput` isn't designed to accept Postscript arguments.

Comment: @A.Ellett: Can you guess the reason why it was designed without supporting RPN for the first argument? You can make your comment as your answer.

Comment: @A.Ellett: you do not understand the meaning and definition of the different arguments. `\uput` understands PS arguments.

Comment: It is a bug that was left just for a historical reason. :-)

Comment: @Herbert I'm not sure why you think I don't understand the command.  Do you have a working example for `\uput`?  I pass postscripts through pstricks macros quite a bit, but for `\uput` I couldn't get them to work.  But if you could point out what I'm missing and show me how to get it to work with `\uput`, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @A.Ellett: `labelsep` is a _length_ it must have a unit! If it is missing then the current `\psunit` is taken into account. If I allow a PostScript expression for such a length then it can only be used in PS expressions, but labelsep is also used for placing labels on TeX level where we have to use TeX notation. It is no problem to allow `{! 2 sqrt}` but it fails if one uses this for labels of a axis.

Comment: @Herbert: Your explanation still leaves a confusion. If `\uput`  was created to work in both PS and TeX level, why can only the first argument NOT accept PS expression while its other arguments can? I think you can make it automatically detect the surrounding environment whether TeX or PS world. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the newest `pstricks` package, the `labelsep` of `\uput` can accept RPN expression (without unit) and it takes the active unit.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\SpecialCoor
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-1)(3,3)
    \pscircle(1,1){!2 sqrt}
    \uput{!2 sqrt}[45](1,1){\qdisk(0,0){2pt}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This isn't an issue about RPN or not.  This is about the ability to pass Postscript commands through `\uput`.  This doesn't seem to work.  I'm drawing a complete blank why.  Someone better acquainted with the internals of `pstricks` can explain that.

But, I'm assuming that you want to be able to make some kind of contextually dependent decisions on how text is placed (if not, then just write the actual values in).  You can use a bit of `expl3` magic to get this done as in the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%..%
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\fpsqrt}{ m }
    {
        \fp_eval:n {  #1 ^ ( 1 / 2 ) }        
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%..%
\usepackage{pstricks}
\psset{unit=0.5cm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

$\sqrt{2}=\fpsqrt{2}$

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-10,-10)(10,10)
    \uput{ \fpsqrt{2} }[0]{30}( 0, 0){Hello World}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

This results in

[image]

Comment: I usually use `fp` package. So I can summarize that it is a bug in PSTricks. :-)

Comment: I didn't recommend `fp` only because the documentation is so poor.

Comment: But its syntax is more beautiful. :D